# Android Webview Image Render to Center rather than top-left corner

Tags: android, webview

The image render in webview starts from the top-left corner of my image which is larger than webview so its scrollable.  I'd like to center the image rather than it rendering to top-left corner...is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling myWebView.loadUrl, you can use plain CSS and call myWebView.loadData instead.

Just make sure to URL Encode any extraneous characters.
Example:

```
myWebView.loadData("<html><head><style type='text/css'>body{margin:auto auto;text-align:center;} img{width:100%25;} </style></head><body><img src='www.mysite.com/myimg.jpeg'/></body></html>" ,"text/html",  "UTF-8");
```